# Prime ideal for the Banach algebra

Tags: ring-theory, banach-algebras

The maximal ideal and Jacobson radical often appear in the Banach algebra theory, but I do not see the prime and nilradical in it.

We can define a prime for a Banach algebra following the ring theory, but few books discuss it. Why? Can Banach algebras contain prime ideals which are not maximal ideals?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, even $C(X)$ (for a generic compact hausdorff space $X$ ) has lots of prime ideals which are not maximal. See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35793/prime-ideals-in-c0-1) and the references given there. In fact as a ring $C(X)$ is $\infty$-dimensional. It makes more sense to consider *closed* prime ideals.

Comment: How about the prime radical?